# overflow, round-off error

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

a) If the following function is written in a program, in what range of x would overflow or zero divide originated from round-off error occur?

> $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-tanh(x)}$

Assume that the smallest positive number is 3 x 10 ^ 39 and machine epsilon is $1.2 x {10^-}^1$

b) rewrite the equation so that no subtraction is necessary.

Comment: Your constants seem for IEEE single precision but are badly in error: They should be $\epsilon=1.19\times 10^{-7}\;$ and $1.18\times 10^{-38}.$ Or do you mean **largest** positive number?

Comment: @gammatester the constants are correct as is.

Comment: I strongly doubt that. On what FP system is $3\times10^{39}$ the **smallest** positive number and $0.12$ the machine epsilon? And how can the machine epsilon be **smaller** that the smallest positive number?  Can the number 1 represented in you system? (It is smaller the smallest positive number!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express $\tanh x$ with the exponential function:
$$\tanh x = \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$$
and get
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-\tanh x}=\frac{1}{1 - \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}}= 
\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}+1-(e^{2x}-1)}=\frac{e^{2x}+1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{e^{2x}}{2}$$
Obviously overflow cannot be avoided for large x because the function goes to $\infty$, but my expression does not suffer from cancellation error for large $x$ where $\tanh x \approx 1.$

And since you do not have corrected your machine/arithmetic constants, your range questions have no definit answers (e.g. division by zero would occur if $\tanh x -1=0$ in your arithmetic, for IEEE single this would be for $x > 9.1$)